# How do I perform timedelta and date comparison in Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby

In Python, if I want to check for a specific date + 24 hours has passed, I will write:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

some_date = datetime(2013, 1, 10, 11, 0)
day = timedelta(1)

# Checks if some_date + 1 day is before today's date
print some_date + day < datetime.now()
```

How can I construct a time difference of 1 day and checks if a specific date + 1 day is before today's date in Ruby?

Comment: Is [duration](http://rubyforge.org/projects/duration) what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm trying to use libraries from within Ruby 1.9.3 without resorting to outside gems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'time'

xmas = DateTime.new(2013, 12, 25)
puts x = xmas + 1 # 2013-12-26T00:00:00+00:00
d = DateTime.now
puts x > d        # true
puts x - d        # 30167183979194791/86400000000000 (a Rational)
puts d >> 12      # 2014-01-10T21:15:20+01:00
```

Comment: What if I wanted the time difference to be in seconds or years? How is that done?

Comment: The `1` is actually in seconds, `86400` is the right value for the next day, at least in Ruby 1.9.3.  Maybe the 1 is one day in another Ruby version.

Comment: @Thierry Lam Yes, I was mistaken. I meant DateTime, not Time. See edited answer.